# VSCode Theme Terminal Highlight

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, themes

I am having some trouble editing this VSCode theme. For some reason, the terminal has a black highlight over everything in it. Even when I don't have anything selected in it, the higlight is there.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTjjI.png)

I am using the "Netflix Red" theme. I tried all the vscode workbench.colorCustomizations tags, but nothing seems to work. Anyone know a way to remove this black highlight?

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Please check if this happens for other terminal profiles. 3) Please show us a screenshot with more textual content in the terminal. I want to see at least two commands and their outputs in a screenshot.